# Were drugs used in early Buddhist traditions?

Tags: buddhism

I'm reading a Wikipedia article on Vajrayana Buddhism and it says: "In Tantric Buddhism, which originated in the Tibeto-Himalayan region, cannabis serves as an important part of a traditional ritual..."

It cites a journal that I don't have access to, so I can't look too much deeper into the source.

What's the historical background of this claim? Are there serious documents or Buddhist texts showing the use of cannabis or other drugs?

Note: Had to ask here because the answers in Buddhism SE were of low quality.

Comment: Was the journal article you were looking for [The religious and medicinal uses of Cannabis in China, India and Tibet](https://www.cnsproductions.com/pdf/Touw.pdf)?

Comment: If so, the source cited there, [The Tantric Tradition](https://archive.org/details/TheTantricTraditionSwamiAghehanandaBharati_201709), by Aghehananda Bharati, is available on archive.org

Comment: Data on this topic may be more likely found in archaeology than written sources. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-52847175

Answer (score 2):

As @sempaiscuba points out in a comment, the source cited for that statement on Wikipedia is  "The Religious and Medicinal Uses of Cannabis in China, India and Tibet" by Mia Touw and [the full text is available](https://www.cnsproductions.com/pdf/Touw.pdf). Here is the relevant quote:

> Though little has been written on the use of cannabis in the Himalayas and the Tibetan plateau, no doubt due to the inaccessibility, of the region for study, there are clear indications that the plant is more highly valued and more consistently  used  there   than   anywhere   else.   It  was traditionally  considered  sacred  in  Tibet  ([Aldrich  1977](https://sci-hub.tw/https://doi.org/10.1080/02791072.1977.10472053)). [...] In Tantric    Buddhism,    which    flowered    in    the    Tibeto-Himalayan  region,  cannabis  is  an  important  part  of  the meditative  ritual  which  may  or  may  not  include  sexual intercourse.  It  is  taken  to  facilitate  the  meditation  and heighten  awareness  of  all  aspects  of  the  ceremony.  The large   dose,   taken   orally,   is   timed   so   as   to   ensure increasingly  heightened  awareness  from  the  beginning  of the ritual onwards, with the greatest "high"-delayed when taken orally by about an hour and a half-coinciding with the climax of the ceremony  ([Bharati  1965](https://archive.org/details/TheTantricTraditionSwamiAghehanandaBharati)).

From Aldrich:

> Tantric cannabis use in India rose in about the 7th century A.D. in an explosive mingling of the doctrines and practices of Shaivite Hinduism and Tibetan Buddhism. Tantrism reached its height in medieval Bengal and the Himalayan kingdoms...

The substance of the text and rituals described in the article are more Hindu than Buddhist but it is suggested that cannabis use in Tantric ritual had at least some influence on Buddhism, in Nepal and Tibet. The PDF of the Bharati text is not OCRd to copy/paste from, but it similarly seems to be thin on evidence that ritual cannabis use was a major part of Buddhism, as opposed to Hinduism. All of these texts are referring to an early period where the distinction between the two traditions was not yet strong.